# A general method for integration of rational function.

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

$\int\frac {x^3}{1+x^5}$

ATTEMPT:

I did the following substitution:

Let $x=\frac{1}{t}.$

$dx=\frac{-1}{t^2}dt.$

substituting back:

$I=\int\frac{-1}{1+t^5}dt$ which doesn't seems a simpler integration.

Next  i substituted $x=p^\frac{2}{5}.$

$dx=\frac{2}{5}\frac{p^{3/5}}{1+p^2}.$

Now let $p=tan\theta.$

$dp=sec^2\theta$$d\theta.$

substituting back:

$I=\frac{2}{5}\int tan^{3/5}\theta$$d\theta$ which i couldn't integrate further even by trying **By parts** method.

Is there a general approach for problems of the form (not the algebraic twins):

$\int \frac{x^m}{1+x^n}dx$ where $n-m \ne1 $

Comment: did you tried partial fraction decomposition?

Comment: This is a real monster ! $I=\int\frac{1}{1+t^n}dt$ appears in "Table of Integrals, Series, and Products" by I.S. Gradshteyn and I.M. Ryzhik. It corresponds to equation $2.142$. How to prove that ? This is **the** question ! Good luck. ($2.146$ for the initial integral).

Comment: I suppose that partial fraction decomposition would be required using all roots of $x^5=-1$ and everything would be done with complex, I am afraid. I hope you will get something (I give up).

Answer (score 4):

What you already made is $$I=\int\frac {x^3}{1+x^5}dx=-\int\frac {dt}{1+t^5}$$ Now $$1+t^5=\prod_{i=1}^5 (t-\alpha_i)$$ where $\alpha_i=-(-1)^{\frac i5}$ which means that, using partial fraction decomposition, $$\frac {1}{1+t^5}=\sum_{i=1}^5 \frac{\beta_i}{t-\alpha_i}$$ $$\int\frac {dt}{1+t^5}=\sum_{i=1}^5 \beta_i \log({t-\alpha_i})$$ which is simple, except that the $\alpha_i$'s and $\beta_i$'s are complex numbers.

But the real part of $$(a+i b)\log(c+id)=\frac a2\, \log(c^2+d^2)-b\, \tan^{-1} \big(\frac d c\big)$$ and this has to be applied to each term (noticing that four of the roots $\alpha_i$ are conjugated by pairs). So, isolating the case of the real root, we need to combine by pairs the logarithms and the inverse tangents.

This is how,  in "Table of Integrals, Series, and Products" by I.S. Gradshteyn and I.M. Ryzhik, they arrive to equation $2.142$.
$$\frac{1}{20} \left(4 \log (t+1)+\left(\sqrt{5}-1\right) \log \left(t^2+\frac{1}{2}
   \left(\sqrt{5}-1\right) t+1\right)-\left(1+\sqrt{5}\right) \log
   \left(t^2-\frac{1}{2} \left(1+\sqrt{5}\right) t+1\right)-2 \sqrt{10-2
   \sqrt{5}} \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{-4 t+\sqrt{5}+1}{\sqrt{10-2 \sqrt{5}}}\right)+2
   \sqrt{ \left(10+2\sqrt{5}\right)} \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{4 t+\sqrt{5}-1}{\sqrt{
   \left(10+2\sqrt{5}\right)}}\right)\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

There is a general closed form for such integrals but it's not elementary or pretty at all.

$$\int \frac{x^m}{1+x^n} \, \mathrm{d}x = \frac{x^{m+1} \, _2F_1\left(1, \frac{m+1}{n};\frac{m+n+1}{n}; -x^n\right)}{m+1} + \mathrm{C}.$$

Where $_2F_1\left(a, b;c; x\right)$ is the hypergeometric function.

With regards to your specific problem, try partial fractions (although I suspect you may have mistyped, given how ugly this is)

$$\frac{x^3}{1+x^5} = \frac{\sqrt{5}x - 5x + \sqrt{5} + 5}{5\sqrt{5}(2x^2 + \sqrt{5}x - x + 2)} + \frac{\sqrt{5}x + 5x + \sqrt{5} - 5}{5\sqrt{5}(2x^2 - \sqrt{5}x - x + 2)} - \frac{1}{5(x+1)}.$$

Comment: But how one could get that partial fractions without  using wolfram? All i could exploit from the question was just the fact that $1+x^5=(1+x)(x^4-x^3+x^2-x+1)$ which is really complex to decompose further without using  wolfram.